# Background location tracking not working in apk but working in debug mode

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, location

Actually I'm developing an app in react native which requires background location access it's working fine in debug mode but when I generate apk it's not working. My question is do I have to submit it to play console even if the app is for testing to test the apk?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to added permission to your project.
https://docs.expo.dev/guides/permissions/
Just follow this doc or you can add permission into react native project also..

Comment: I have all the permissions in the manifest file everythings works fine in debug mode but not working in apk ,i dont what is causing the issue location or task manager